# nested models in django templates

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

im building a survey app or something similar, each question has three or more answer, i cant get it works that in the template, i mean, nest the question with the corresponding answers, this are my models:

```
class Trivia(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categorias)
    contador = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
      return self.nombre

class Meta():
    verbose_name_plural = "Trivias" 

class Preguntas(models.Model):
    trivia = models.ForeignKey(Trivia)
    pregunta = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pregunta

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "Preguntas"

class Respuestas(models.Model):
    Pregunta = models.ForeignKey(Preguntas)
    respuesta = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.respuesta

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "Respuestas"
```

and my views:

```
class TriviaView(ListView):
    model = Preguntas
    paginate_by = 1
    template_name = 'trivias.html'
```

And this my template:

```
 <p>{% for pregunta in object_list %} {{pregunta.pregunta}} {% endfor %}</p>
```

How can i nest the question with their corresponding answers?

Sorry for the spanish attributes named, my client asked like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List of `Respuestas` is available as the `pregunta.respuestas_set` [backward relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) queryset:

```
{% for pregunta in object_list %}
    {{ pregunta.pregunta }}
    <ul>
    {% for respuesta in pregunta.respuestas_set.all %}
        <li>{{ respuesta.respuesta }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```